# Go, Golang : travis error for main program, go get -v

Tags: testing, go, travis-ci

In my repo's subdirectory, I have some scripts with `package main` to show some example usage fo my package. But this gives me the following errors when being tested on Travis.

```
 repo

 example-dir
      sub-dir
          main.go  // this gives me error like the following
```

`github.com/~/directory-for-main-program
The command "go get -v ./..." failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.`

I see this error only in Travis , not in local machine with `go test`.

Is there anyway to separate the main program and still able to pass the Travis testing?

Comment: You're not using the right import path in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the correct path in your `main.go`, which is the proper way or use [build constraints](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) to disable that file:

```
// +build local

package main

//other code
```

then to locally build it use `go build -tags local` or `go run -tags local`